# Openshift web console inaccessible all of sudden

Tags: openshift, openshift-enterprise

The Openshift web console inaccessible  all of sudden and i can execute all on OC CLI.

```
oc cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://api.xxxxxx.com:6443
To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.

oc whoami --show-console
https://console-openshift-console.apps.xxx.com
```

when i try to access the console ,

This site can’t be reached
console-openshift-console.apps.xxxx.com unexpectedly closed the connection.

Please help.